# Hover on CSS is not working for my navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am messing around with web development, I have fallen into an issue with the hover section of CSS i cant get it to work on my site.

I did have this working when i had the navigation going vertical but then decided to have it horizontal instead which is where the issues started.

I have searched this on StackOverflow and have checked google but non of the solutions seem to help. Sorry if my code is a bit messy i will show you the sections that you need from the HTML and the CSS

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.html"><b><font size="5">Home</font></b></a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html"><b><font size="5">About</font></b></a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUs.html"><b><font size="5">Contact Us</font></b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    /*width: 200px;*/
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 10%, #2E3E9F 90%);
}

li{
    float: left;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: it works, grey hover with white text

Comment: For some reason on my browser its not picking it up which is strange could i ask what browser you are using please :)

Comment: its working fine check https://jsfiddle.net/p7tLjnov/

Comment: tested on chrome

Comment: its working fine on chrome as well as IE.
Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its not great to use `!important` though. (Chrome)

```css
  #nav {
  /*width: 200px;*/
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 10%, #2E3E9F 90%);
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: grey !important;
  color: white !important;
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html"><b><font size="5">Home</font></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html"><b><font size="5">About</font></b></a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactUs.html"><b><font size="5">Contact Us</font></b></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me!
I think it might just be some sort of issue on my end as i have tested your code in the 'Run code snippet' and it works fine have also tested a suggestion made by somebody else to run it from jsfiddel and it worked on there so it must be something happening on my PC

Comment: 1. did u try adding important to your code and checking if it works? something maybe overriding. 2. also clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: I found out what the issue was it actually didn't stem from the navigation code the problem was in my body div. I had to comment everything out and find the cause but eventually did and I have learnt a fair bit whilst doing so! thanks for all your help.

Comment: oh ok. have a great day.